# Populating a Datetime Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I want to populate a datetime column on the fly within a stored procedure. below is the query that I currently have that does same but slows down query performance.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TaxVal
(
    ID         INT
    , PaidDate DATETIME
    , CustID   INT
    , CompID   INT 
)

INSERT INTO #TaxVal(ID, PaidDate, CustID, CompID)
VALUES(01, '20150201',12, 100)
    , (03,'20150301', 18,101)
    , (10,'20150401',19,22)
    , (17,'20150401',02,11)
    , (11,'20150411',18,201)
    , (78,'20150421',18,299)
    , (133,'20150407',18,101)

--  SELECT * FROM #TaxVal

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20150101'
    , @EndDate     DATETIME = '20150501'

DECLARE @Tab TABLE 
(
    CompID    INT
    , DateField DATETIME
)

DECLARE @T INT
SET @T = 0
WHILE @EndDate >= @StartDate + @T 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Tab 
    SELECT CompID
         , @StartDate + @T AS DateField
    FROM #TaxVal
    WHERE CustID = 18
        AND CompID = 101
    ORDER BY DateField DESC

    SET @T = @T + 1
END

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @Tab 

DROP TABLE #TaxVal
```

Which is the best way to write this query for better performance?

Comment: Try a common table expression (CTE) or use a _numbers table_ to generate the set of dates and insert them in one go. A search for **sql server generate dates** should get you started. Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Could you please give an example.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
DECLARE @T INT
SET @T = 0
WHILE @EndDate >= @StartDate + @T 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Tab 
SELECT CompID
     , @StartDate + @T AS DateField
FROM #TaxVal
WHERE CustID = 18
    AND CompID = 101
ORDER BY DateField DESC

SET @T = @T + 1
END
```

to this:

```
;with cte as(
select cast('20150101' as date) as d
union all
select dateadd(dd, 1, d) as d from cte where d < '20150501'
)
INSERT INTO @Tab
SELECT CompID, d
FROM #TaxVal 
cross join cte
WHERE CustID = 18 AND CompID = 101
Option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Here is `recursive common table expression` to get all dates in range. Then you do a `cross join` and insert. Notice that there is no sense to order set while inserting.

Comment: Thanks. I get the error The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Answer (score 0):

Giorgi's answer of

```
;with cte as(
select cast('20150101' as date) as d
union all
select dateadd(dd, 1, d) as d from cte where d < '20150501'
)
INSERT INTO @Tab
SELECT CompID, d
FROM #TaxVal 
cross join cte
WHERE CustID = 18 AND CompID = 101
```

will work, but be careful with recursive CTE's.  If the date range is large, you'll quickly hit your maximum recursion level.  Often, a numbers table is used much like HABO mentioned.  This is simply a table with a single column that only a integer so the rows would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.  You can then join the Numbers table (outer apply works well for this) and use the numbers with dateadd to get your incremental dates.  Also note that you can run into an issue where the Numbers table doesn't contain enough rows for you date range.

Comment: In order to not hit the limit, option(maxrecuraion 0) is used. Thx, I have exited my answer.