# Missing Zero Values; Date Join for Zero Values by Company

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is T-SQL on a SQL Server database.

I have a query that is supposed to create a trailing 30 days of dates.  Then, I am joining the number of tickets created on each of those dates and separating this out by company.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
   dt.dt,
   CASE 
      WHEN tcr.CreatedCount IS NULL 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE tcr.CreatedCount 
   END AS 'CreatedCount',
   CASE 
      WHEN tcl.ClosedCount IS NULL 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE tcl.ClosedCount 
   END AS 'ClosedCount',
   tcr.cname
FROM
   (SELECT 
       dt = cast(DATEADD(DAY, (- 1 * n), getdate()) AS date)
    FROM
       (SELECT TOP (30) 
           n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m1.number) - 1
        FROM 
           [master].dbo.spt_values AS m1
        CROSS JOIN 
           [master].dbo.spt_values AS m2) X
    ) dt
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(a.TicketNbr) AS CreatedCount,
        CAST(a.date_entered AS date) AS 'DayCreated',
        a.company_name cname,
        a.company_recid cid
     FROM 
        v_rpt_Service a
     LEFT JOIN 
        Company ON a.company_name = Company.Company_Name
     WHERE 
        (a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Incident'
         OR a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Service' 
         OR a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Escalation')
     GROUP BY 
         CAST(a.date_entered AS date), a.company_name, a.company_recid) tcr ON dt.dt = tcr.DayCreated
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT 
       COUNT(a.TicketNbr) AS ClosedCount,
       CAST(a.date_closed AS date) AS 'DayClosed',
       a.company_recid
    FROM 
       v_rpt_Service a
    LEFT JOIN 
       Company ON a.company_name = Company.Company_Name
    WHERE 
       (a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Incident' OR
        a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Service' OR
        a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Escalation')
    GROUP BY 
       CAST(a.date_closed AS date), a.company_recid) tcl ON dt.dt = tcl.DayClosed AND tcl.company_recid = tcr.cid
ORDER BY 
    cname, dt
```

The idea is that the data shows a month of dates for each company with created and closed counts by date. Currently, it shows 0 counts for `closed` tickets, but not `created`. Any date where there are no created tickets are completely omitted.

Here is the sample data that is *almost* where I need it to be:

[image: Query Sample Data]

How can I get this query to show all rows, and not omit those rows that have 0 created count?

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned that I can't use `WITH x AS` or parameters.  This query is going into a 3rd party reporting application that refuses these things.

Comment: Sorry, but the code is more or less unreadable. If you edit it, it will be easier for us to help you!

Comment: @jarlh I'm not really sure how to make it more readable.  I made an attempt; did that help?

Comment: Your issues sounds like you're missing dates simply because you don't have data for those dates.  In that case, you need a table of nothing but 30 days of consecutive dates and then left join your data to it.  Here is a similar post where someone was doing this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945952/populating-a-datetime-column/29946733#29946733

Comment: @Scott I am getting the 30 days cleanly with the `dt` table.  If I do this without the companies, it gives me a clean month with everything working properly.  It only breaks when I add in the companies.

Comment: Sonny, your problem isn't that you are missing days; the problem is that you are missing days with companies.  You need to start with a list of all valid companies, cross join that with a list of thirty dates, and then go out from there to see created dates.  Query forthcoming ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need a full list of every company (with every day) before you check for created and closed.  I wager that if you examine your results, you'll find that you have at least one record for each of your thirty days.

Try first getting a list of all companies, then combining that with a list of all dates, and going from there.  I took a stab at it below:

```
SELECT 
   dt.dt,
   CASE 
      WHEN tcr.CreatedCount IS NULL 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE tcr.CreatedCount 
   END AS 'CreatedCount',
   CASE 
      WHEN tcl.ClosedCount IS NULL 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE tcl.ClosedCount 
   END AS 'ClosedCount',
   c.cname
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT company_recid, company_name AS cname
    FROM v_rpt_service) c 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       dt = cast(DATEADD(DAY, (- 1 * n), getdate()) AS date)
    FROM
       (SELECT TOP (30) 
           n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m1.number) - 1
        FROM 
           [master].dbo.spt_values AS m1
        CROSS JOIN 
           [master].dbo.spt_values AS m2) X
    ) dt ON 
        1=1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(a.TicketNbr) AS CreatedCount,
        CAST(a.date_entered AS date) AS 'DayCreated',
        a.company_name cname,
        a.company_recid cid
     FROM 
        v_rpt_Service a
     LEFT JOIN 
        Company ON a.company_name = Company.Company_Name
     WHERE 
        (a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Incident'
         OR a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Service' 
         OR a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Escalation')
     GROUP BY 
         CAST(a.date_entered AS date), a.company_name, a.company_recid) tcr ON dt.dt = tcr.DayCreated AND c.Company_recID = tcr.cid 
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT 
       COUNT(a.TicketNbr) AS ClosedCount,
       CAST(a.date_closed AS date) AS 'DayClosed',
       a.company_recid
    FROM 
       v_rpt_Service a
    LEFT JOIN 
       Company ON a.company_name = Company.Company_Name
    WHERE 
       (a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Incident' OR
        a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Service' OR
        a.Board_Name = 'SOC - Escalation')
    GROUP BY 
       CAST(a.date_closed AS date), a.company_recid) tcl ON dt.dt = tcl.DayClosed AND c.Company_recID = tcl.company_recid 
ORDER BY 
    cname, dt
```

Comment: You're a wizard.  I'm hugging you...metaphorically speaking.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using master.dbo.spt_values as the way to get the date list so only dates that are contained in that table are included in the output, but I could be mistaken.

If you are looking to include all dates then you might be better off using a CTE to generate the required dates. In this example below it cross joins the dates so that every date is joined with every company. It then left joins both counts to the date and company which should ensure that all dates for all companies are returned.

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEADD(d,-29,@EndDate)

;WITH DateRanges AS
(SELECT @StartDate AS DateValue
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, DateValue) AS DateValue
FROM DateRanges
WHERE DateValue < @EndDate)

SELECT 
    d.DateValue AS Date, 
    c.Company_Name,
    ISNULL(tcr.CreatedCount,0) AS CreatedCount, 
    ISNULL(tcl.ClosedCount,0) AS ClosedCount

FROM DateRanges d
CROSS JOIN Company c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                COUNT(a.TicketNbr) AS CreatedCount, 
                CAST(a.date_entered AS date) AS 'DayCreated', 
                a.company_name AS cname, 
                a.company_recid AS cid
            FROM v_rpt_Service a 
            LEFT JOIN Company c
                ON a.company_name = c.Company_Name
            WHERE a.Board_Name IN ('SOC - Incident','SOC - Service','SOC - Escalation')
            GROUP BY 
                CAST(a.date_entered AS date), 
                a.company_name, 
                a.company_recid) tcr 
    ON d.DateValue = tcr.DayCreated 
    AND c.company_recid = tcr.company_recid

LEFT JOIN (SELECT      
                COUNT(a.TicketNbr) AS ClosedCount, 
                CAST(a.date_closed AS date) AS 'DayClosed', 
                a.company_recid
            FROM v_rpt_Service a
            WHERE a.Board_Name IN ('SOC - Incident','SOC - Service','SOC - Escalation')
            GROUP BY CAST(a.date_closed AS date), a.company_recid) tcl 
    ON d.DateValue = tcl.DayClosed 
    AND tcl.company_recid = tcr.company_recid
```

Comment: The OP's code is already getting an uninterrupted list of the past thirty days; running the `dt` derived table confirms this.  The issue isn't with his dates table

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote this.  I should have mentioned that I cannot use `WITH / AS` or parameters due to the nature of the project.  This query is made to go into a 3rd party reporting program.  Also, I tried this in SSMS and am only getting 0 values.  I may be able to tinker with it a bit.